# What happens to my 2nd wife if I stop being polygamous in CK3?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I am playing as the High King of Ireland, who, as an Insular Christian, is *required* to have 3 wives if I don't want a piety generation penalty.

When my half-sister died, it pushed me into a mental break, and I was given a choice where one of the options was to convert to Paulicianism, another Christian sect. The big difference though, is that Paulicans are *monogamous*.

If I make the switch, what happens to my existing marriages? Do they get annulled? Stick around? (but don't do it again, buster!) Is this true even when switching to a faith that doesn't allow divorces?

I wasn't willing to risk it (and am playing Ironman) so I did not find out.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I just tested this as an Ash'ari (Muslim) ruler converting to Catholicism.

This is what happened to my 3 secondary wives:

- I received 3 messages which read "Spouse Invalid - Your new Faith's beliefs mean that [name] is no longer your spouse".
- They became regular courtiers in my court.
- They did not change their religions (but my primary wife didn't either)
- They did not have an opinion penalty for being divorced (just one for me being an Evil [sic] Catholic).
- A couple days later, one of my ex-wives informed me that she is pregnant and that "Since we were married when this child was conceived, there is no stain of bastardy; when the babe is born it will be known as your legitimate offspring".

So TL;DR: Converting to a monogamous religion will get you a "free" divorce from your secondary wives without any of the usual restrictions, costs or penalties.

Comment: A [sic] on "Your new Faith's believes" as well?

Comment: The [sic] behind "Evil" was not to point out any orthographic error, but the description of a religion as evil. I wanted to make clear that it's the game which calls Catholicism evil in that context, not me.

Comment: "Quotation marks" would've worked as well ;-)